# Javascript: laggy on hover; animate slide

Tags: javascript, animation, onhover

I have this infobox that will slide to show on hover on a arrow connected to that infobox. See the jsfiddle I've linked further down for more insight.

The thing I'm struggling with is that it's sort of laggy. It jumps back and forth really fast as it likes and it bothers me a lot. I've done some research and found out that the `.stop(true, false)` is the thing messing it up, but that you can't really go without it either. Haven't found any smooth solution yet though...

I would like it, if possible, to...

1. ...when hovered, fully animate the animation even though the mouse leaves.
2. ...animate when `#infoboxArrow` is hovered and then animate back when the mouse leaves its parent `#infocontainer`.

```js
$('#infoboxArrow').hover(function() {
  $('#infocontainer')
  .stop(true, false)
  .animate({
    right: 250
  }, 600);
}, function() {
  $('#infocontainer')
  .stop(true, false)
  .animate({
    right: 0
  }, 600);
});
```

```css
#infocontainer{
  position:fixed;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 0em;
  right: 0em;
}

#infoboxArrow {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: pink;
  margin-bottom: 10.1325em;
  margin-top: 10.1325em;
  height: 7.735em;
}

#infoboxDiv{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 400px;
  height: 28em;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="infocontainer"  class="slideOutTab">
  <div id ="infoboxArrow" class="slideOutTab"><img src="http://i61.tinypic.com/qmx8ns.png"/></div>
  <div id="infoboxDiv" class="slideOutTab"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try listening to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events instead of `hover`:

```js
var $infocontainer = $('#infocontainer');
$('#infoboxArrow').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $infocontainer
  .stop(true, false)
  .animate({
    right: 250
  }, 600);
});
$infocontainer.on('mouseleave', function() {
  $infocontainer
  .stop(true, false)
  .animate({
    right: 0
  }, 600);
});
```

```js
var $infocontainer = $('#infocontainer');
$('#infoboxArrow').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $infocontainer
  .stop(true, false)
  .animate({
    right: 250
  }, 600);
});
$infocontainer.on('mouseleave', function() {
  $infocontainer
  .stop(true, false)
  .animate({
    right: 0
  }, 600);
});
```

```css
#infocontainer{
  position:fixed;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 0em;
  right: 0em;
}
#infoboxArrow {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: pink;
  margin-bottom: 10.1325em;
  margin-top: 10.1325em;
  height: 7.735em;
}
#infoboxDiv{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 400px;
  height: 28em;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="infocontainer"  class="slideOutTab">
  <div id ="infoboxArrow" class="slideOutTab"><img src="http://i61.tinypic.com/qmx8ns.png"/></div>
  <div id="infoboxDiv" class="slideOutTab"></div>
</div>
```

Also note you don't need the image. And you are mixing `em` units with `px`, so your layout could break if the font size changes. Consider this code:

```js
var $infocontainer = $('#infocontainer');
$('#infoboxArrow').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $infocontainer
  .stop(true, false)
  .animate({
    right: 250
  }, 600);
});
$infocontainer.on('mouseleave', function() {
  $infocontainer
  .stop(true, false)
  .animate({
    right: 0
  }, 600);
});
```

```css
#infocontainer{
  position: fixed;
  height: 28em;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 0em;
  right: 0em;
}
#infoboxArrow {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -59px;
  border: 59px solid #FFC0CB;
  border-right: 100px solid #000000;
  border-left: none;
}
#infoboxDiv{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="infocontainer"  class="slideOutTab">
  <div id="infoboxArrow" class="slideOutTab"></div>
  <div id="infoboxDiv" class="slideOutTab"></div>
</div>
```